# Angular2. package.json dependency name

Tags: json, angular, npm

I'm looking at the official [angular2-quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#package-json)...

Looking at **package.json**, I see :

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
  "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",

  "systemjs": "0.19.27",
  "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

  "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
}
```

Reading other tutorials on the web, the `@angular/...` are replaced with `angular2`. Why is it so? 2 different packages for angular2?

I ask because running the Angular2-quickstart code on my machine the `system.src.js` file and the `app` folder are not found...

Also can the `@angular` thing be the problem of my issue ?

Comment: This formulation is IMHO a bit unclear: "@angular/... are replaced with angular2". `@angular` is the new and `angular2` the old name.

Comment: No idea what you mean by this comment. I just tried to ensure we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: Seems you have some kind of problem with me. No idea what it is about.

Comment: Catalin Besleaga, why that attitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `angular2` name in modules names is for versions before RC (release candidate) versions (beta ones) and the `@angular` one for RC versions.

RC versions are really fresh so most of tutorials use beta versions...

Comment: RCs (release candidates) are after beta versions. Final release versions are closer ;-) So it's supposed to be more stable...

Comment: How can I find the RC packages on NPMjs.com ?

Comment: In fact you need to import the following packages: `@angular/common`, `@angular/compiler`, `@angular/core`, `@angular/http`, `@angular/platform-browser`, `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`, `@angular/router`, `@angular/router-deprecated` instead of the single `angular2` one...

Comment: that's kinf of Obvious.

Comment: In fact there are some "not so obvious" changes between beta and rc versions ;-)

Comment: That's what you told me in your answer

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `@angular` is the Angular namespace name in the NPM repository.